# What are some approaches for In-app UX for API documentation?

Tags: documentation, api

I’m working on this platform-as-a-service product for developers. We have a web GUI and an API, and I’m trying to think of ways to bring these closer together such that the developers can interact with the web app and learn what API calls are available (+copy/paste API code snippets, etc.) as they go along without context-switching to the docs.

I'm trying to make the API reference experience more interactive and contextual to answer the question "Hey, all these things that I can do on this app page, how do I do/automate them using the API?"

My approach is to have a dismissable side panel where there would be a list of API code snippets that are related to the current page the user is on.

As the user interacts with the page (fills inputs, toggles switches, checks checkboxes, etc) that triggers changes in this API side panel's code snippets. Basically, the user is building their code snippets interactively, if that makes sense.

Has anyone here done something like this? Is there a different/better approach to educating developers about the available APIs within the product itself?

Comment: Have you done any observational user research yet? Before settling on a UI pattern, you might want to understand what can be done in Postman or the user's "natural habitat".

Comment: No, no observational research yet, unfortunately. We already have an API docs page with interactivity to it that builds your snippets, I just want to explore ways to get that to the next level. I'll have a look at Postman, thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend it - if you can get time with some senior API developers, they can tell you about their best and worst experiences (with your PAAS platform and others). DX is an interesting space, users tend to value consistency and clarity over inventing new patterns.

Comment: Reposting the question doesn't prevent it from being closed again. The problem with the question is that there is no problem to be solved. If you can explain what would be a "different/better approach" by describing the problem with your current approach you would actually have a valid question for this site.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think platforms like Storybook and CodePen provide examples of how to integrate technical details into a user interface that can be made more user friendly than it has been done in the past, which is to just provide text or images but no actual details that you can interact with.

Other examples that I can think of include Jupyter Notebook, Wolfram Alpha and even some of the 'no-code' programming platforms that creates a set of design interface elements to distinguish between text documentation and code blocks that you can interact with.